# on the border vs along the border

Tags: prepositions

which is the correct use of preposition with border?

1.The ceasefire agreement is now alive only in the breach, with violations intensifying in number and much damage to life and livelihood **on/along** the border.

2.Peace **on/along** the border is difficult to achieve at the tactical level by military leaders.

Comment: Literally speaking, 'along the border' means the area around the border (including the border, while 'on the border' means exactly on the border. I believe in both these cases, along the border would work better than on the border.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['On the border' v. 'at the border'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/250902/on-the-border-v-at-the-border)

Comment: it does not talk about along the border

Comment: 'Along' suggests the whole length of the border. 'On' *slightly* suggests a point on the border. I agree with ĴØË ĸĚʀŖ : 'along' works better in both cases.